# In linear models, why are we focused on BLUE rather than UMVUE?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, optimization, linear-model, umvue, blue

It seems more natural to talk about UMVUE (following the basic statistical estimation theory). But when we turn to lm, we only care about BLUE, why? Are there any insurmountable difficulties here?

Comment: The statement "we only care..." is baseless.

Answer (score 2):

The BLUE of an estimable linear parametric function (elpf) is literally the **linear** analogue of UMVUE. Like as in the case of UMVUE, an elpf is BLUE if and only if it is uncorrelated with every linear zero functions (lzf).

When in $\langle \mathbf y, \mathbf X\boldsymbol\beta, \sigma^2\mathbb I\rangle, $ the dependent vector is following multivariate normal distribution, then the BLUE of any elpf is UMVUE and and any lzf is ancillary to it.

---

### Reference:

$\rm [I]$ Linear Models: An Integrated Approach, *Debasis Sengupta, Sreenivasa Rao Jammalamadaka,* World Scientific, $2003, $ sec. $4.3.$